# Calculation Keyphraseness in Wikification

Tags: python, neo4j, wikipedia

I am trying to implement a system which would map wikipedia into a graph where nodes are the article titles, links and the edges are the relationships between them.

This process is called wikification and has already been [implemented](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Emihalcea/papers/mihalcea.cikm07.pdf).

My approach till now has been  as follows :

- Map all nodes as topics/categories/pageform/surfaceform into a Neo4j  database.
- Assign relationships to them as links/redirects/is-a-category

Now, I need to calculate the keyphraseness of each link. The keyphraseness is defined as :

```
    k(n) = no. of articles term appeared as alink/ no. of articles term appeared in
```

I would like to have some suggestions on how to store my links so that I can calculate the keyphraseness with minimum time complexity.

Right now, for every node in my graph I would have to parse 4M articles to calculate it.

NOTE: A surface form in wikipedia is a page that redirects to another page.

Comment: In order to do this quickly, you'll need the terms to be individual nodes, linked to other nodes representing articles.  This requires that you text process all of the contents of all of the articles.  Wikipedia is huge.  The number of terms in each article is potentially huge.  You should think carefully before you attempt this, or do it on a small subset.  A graph structure like this should permit you to write a query to calculate k(n).   `(t:Term)-[:in]->(a:Article)-[:in]->(c:Category)`   Assume a "link" boolean attribute on term nodes, indicating whether it was a part of a link or not.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the Wikipedia [mysql database dump](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html). From that database you can easily find the count of the articles that has a phrase as a link in them.

For the parts that you need to find different frequencies and document frequencies of phrases in Wikipedia, you can use [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/) API to index Wikipedia and then Lucene gives you a great range of functions to get different frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

I actually did something similar once a few years ago. 
I calculated keyphraseness a little bit simplified though:

k(n) = no of times term appeared as a link / no. of times term appeared in total

But the value was very useful to extract keywords nevertheless.
What i did was i first iterated over all articles in the dump, parsed them and collected a so called anchor index which contained all the anchor texts of all links in wikipedia and incremented a counter for every anchor term (you could also just increment once for every page to get to your value). I then stored this index as a sorted String[] Array in memory and iterated over all articles again and looked up all 9-gramms from the article text in the anchor index, if it was present i incremented the "total" counter for this term (you could just increment once for every article).

I did this with java and simple for loops on arrays, it was feasible (less than 2 days calculation time on a Machine with 16gb of ram and a AMD phenom ii x4 955. processor.)

It was a english wikipedia of 2011, it extracted 92,893,007 links which led to a term lexicon of 13,585,647 terms mapped to 3,428,014 articles/concepts. I still have the data lying around if you want to use it.